# issue with using devise ajax authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I'm using this [tutorial](http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-set-up-devise-ajax-authentication-with-rails-4-0/) to make ajax requests for sign-in and sign-up, the issue is that the request returns a 201 code but current_user is still `nil` on the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with CSRF token it wasn't updated with every request !